# How to underline links in the navbar using Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to apply custom CSS styling to the Bootstrap navbar, so that the link text is underlined on mouseover. I'd also like the underline to fade in.

Here is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/xfddh0r5/

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #439348;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #439348;
}
```

I've noticed two strange problems:

- The underline appears at the bottom of the navbar, rather than directly under the text.
- The link 'area' for the menu items seems to be too big. Ideally just the text would be a link.

Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reset the `padding` to `0` or decrease the values. And use `margin` to adjust the spacing again.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0; /*removing spacing*/
  margin: 14px; /*add spacing*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this doesn't quite seem to be working, the underline is still too wide. Also, the blank space above the text seems to be part of the link.

Comment: updated the answer, you can rest all padding to 0 if you want.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to CSS. The menu links then get all squished in the top right. Perhaps I need to alter the padding on the [li] element instead? Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant! Seems to have got it :) I'll mark as answered, but where did you get 14px from?

Comment: from guessing, bootstrap uses 14px as the default font size, you don't have to use it, adjust it until you're happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

The links have a lot of padding to make them easy to click on. If you want to apply a border to the text, you can put the text inside a span, and apply the style to that.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="active"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Item 1</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Item 2</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

You can accomplish the fade using CSS transitions:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover > span {
  border-bottom-color: #439348;
  transition: border 1s linear;
}
```